# Affect only one div among 3 divs having the same properties after hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have been working on this project for a while and it works fine but when I implement it, it stops working:

```css
.carousel-promo {
    font:normal 14px sans-serif;
    position:relative;
}

.carousel-promo.item{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-promo button{
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color:  #87bae1;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
 z-index:20;
}

.carousel-promo .product-out-of-stock{
    color: #c15017;;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 55px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 95px;
    height: 32px;
 z-index:20;
 position:relative;
}

.carousel-promo .product-price{
    float: right;
    margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 6px;
 z-index:20;
}

.carousel-promo .product-price .price-old{

 text-decoration: line-through;
 color: #888888;
}

.carousel-promo .product-price .price-old{

 color: #ee001c;
}

.carousel-promo .sale_badge{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:2;
 width:60px;
 height:60px;
 transition: all 150ms ease-in-out 0s;
 border-radius: 0 0 30px 0;
 line-height:60px;
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 font-size:14px;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#83d4fb;
 text-align:center;
}

.carousel-promo > div:hover .sale_badge {
 width:70px;
 height:70px;
 line-height:70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-promo">  
 <div class="item">
  <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x150"  alt="" /></div>
 </div>
  
    
 <div class="item">
  <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x150"  alt="" /></div>
 </div>
  
    
 <div class="item">
  <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
  <div class="image"><img src="https://placehold.it/300x150"  alt="" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

After running the snippet, when you will over a div, the size of the price tag of that specific div will increase.
Once I implement it, when I hover one div, all the price tag increase.

I am using `owlcarousel` to slide the item and my original html code is the following (the CSS is the same as what I have been working with since):

```html
<div class="container-promo">
 
 <h3>Article en promotion</h3>
 
 <div class="carousel-promo">
  
  <div class="item">
   <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
   <div class="image"><img src="images/13.jpg"  alt="" /></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
   <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
   <div class="image"><img src="images/14.jpg"  alt="" /></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="item">
   <div class="sale_badge">-20%</div>
   <div class="image"><img src="images/15.jpg"  alt="" /></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Kindly help me solve this problem.

Sorry I am not a native english speaker, I am trying my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are targeting div tag on hover, while owl-carousel adds some wrapper divs as well. So, logically when ever we hover over a div code works and all price tags shows up. You may have to target your price tags in this specific way so that only .item class hover takes that css effect. So, change you last css code line

```
.carousel-promo > div:hover .sale_badge {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    line-height:70px;
}
```

with following code which is just a bit changed than yours

```
.carousel-promo > div.item:hover .sale_badge {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    line-height:70px;
}
```

And so, exact price tags will be shown on hover.